# Why won't the scrolling container display in my popup window, but works outside of it?

Tags: html, css

I have a popup window (within the same page) which I'm attempting to put a container which scrolls horizontally into, yet it distorts the popup window and does not display anything other than the scrollbar. I'm honestly at a loss, can anyone help me here? I've looked around for solutions but I can't find anything that I can see applies to my problem.

If anyone can help, or point me in the right direction, I'd be really grateful. The scrollbar works perfectly fine when isolated, but inside the window shows like this:

[image]

Standalone:

[image]

My HTML (popup window with scrollbar inside)

```
<div id="formula-popup" class="popup-window">
<div> 
    <a onclick="closeFormulaWindow()" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <span id="ftitle" class="title1"></span>
    <form method="post" id="formulaform" name="edit">
        <span>Current Formula</span>
        <p id="current-formula" class="formula">Existing formula</p>
        <input id="id-passer" type="hidden" name="formula-id" value="">
        <!--sort out horizontal scrollbar from bookmarks here later-->
        <input onclick="refreshWindow()" name="edit-formula" type="submit" value="Confirm">
    </form>
    <div class="h-scrollbar">
        <section class="h-scrollbar-container">
            <div class="outer-wrapper">
                <div class="inner-wrapper">
                    <div class="pseudo-item"></div>
                    <div class="pseudo-item"></div>
                    <div class="pseudo-item"></div>
                    <div class="pseudo-item"></div>
                    <div class="pseudo-item"></div>
                    <div class="pseudo-item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pseudo-track"></div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.scrollbar-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.h-scrollbar {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 30vw;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    height: 20vh;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;  
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.h-scrollbar-container {
    width: 100%;
}

.outer-wrapper {
    max-width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: relative;
    scrollbar-color: #d5ac68 #f1db9d;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.pseudo-track {
    background-color: #f1db9d;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    z-index: -10;
}

.outer-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 5px;
}

.outer-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.outer-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #d5ac68;
}

.outer-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #f1db9d;
}

.outer-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    display: none;
}

.inner-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.pseudo-item {
    height: 30px;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    background-color: gray;
}

.pseudo-item:nth-of-type(2n) {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

.popup-window {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 9999;
    display: none;
}

.popup-window div {
    width: 40vw;
    height: 30vw;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto 30%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #213B54;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    padding-right: 1vw;
    padding-bottom: 2vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.close {
    font: Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #067A9F;
    color: #B5E5E7;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.popup-window div .title1 {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #EE6802;
    align-self: center;
}

.popup-window form input[type=submit]:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.popup-window form span {
    color: #EE6802;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.popup-window form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup-window form span, input {
    width: 100%;
}

.popup-window form input[type=submit] {
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #067A9F;
    color: #213B54;
    padding: 14px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was that I forgot to select an element inside the window properly and instead it was selecting all divs and so overriding the CSS properties.